# Autoencoder NOT for images

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch, autoencoder

I have a dataset which I am trying to autoencode with Pytorch (I have been told a convolutional autoencoder is the way to go). Each 'point' in this dataset is a vector of 1024 bits, and I am trying to encode these into vectors with maybe 10 values.

I have been looking at examples but everything that I can find refers to image encoding, so I am struggling to work out how to apply this to my dataset.

For example, for this bit of code making an autoencoder for MNIST dataset:

```
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F

# define the NN architecture
class ConvAutoencoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ConvAutoencoder, self).__init__()
        ## encoder layers ##
        # conv layer (depth from 1 --> 16), 3x3 kernels
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 16, 3, padding=1)  
        # conv layer (depth from 16 --> 4), 3x3 kernels
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(16, 4, 3, padding=1)
        # pooling layer to reduce x-y dims by two; kernel and stride of 2
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
        
        ## decoder layers ##
        ## a kernel of 2 and a stride of 2 will increase the spatial dims by 2
        self.t_conv1 = nn.ConvTranspose2d(4, 16, 2, stride=2)
        self.t_conv2 = nn.ConvTranspose2d(16, 1, 2, stride=2)


    def forward(self, x):
        ## encode ##
        # add hidden layers with relu activation function
        # and maxpooling after
        x = F.relu(self.conv1(x))
        x = self.pool(x)
        # add second hidden layer
        x = F.relu(self.conv2(x))
        x = self.pool(x)  # compressed representation
        
        ## decode ##
        # add transpose conv layers, with relu activation function
        x = F.relu(self.t_conv1(x))
        # output layer (with sigmoid for scaling from 0 to 1)
        x = F.sigmoid(self.t_conv2(x))
                
        return x

# initialize the NN
model = ConvAutoencoder()
print(model)

# specify loss function
criterion = nn.MSELoss()

# specify loss function
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)

# number of epochs to train the model
n_epochs = 30

for epoch in range(1, n_epochs+1):
    # monitor training loss
    train_loss = 0.0
    
    ###################
    # train the model #
    ###################
    for data in train_loader:
        # _ stands in for labels, here
        # no need to flatten images
        images, _ = data
        # clear the gradients of all optimized variables
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        # forward pass: compute predicted outputs by passing inputs to the model
        outputs = model(images)
        # calculate the loss
        loss = criterion(outputs, images)
        # backward pass: compute gradient of the loss with respect to model parameters
        loss.backward()
        # perform a single optimization step (parameter update)
        optimizer.step()
        # update running training loss
        train_loss += loss.item()*images.size(0)
            
    # print avg training statistics 
    train_loss = train_loss/len(train_loader)
    print('Epoch: {} \tTraining Loss: {:.6f}'.format(
        epoch, 
        train_loss
        ))
```

What would I need to change in something like this to make it suitable for my data? Is there another type of autoencoder that would be more suitable?

Any help or guidance really appreciated!

Comment: A NN autoencoder can do linear and non-linear transformations, given a linear or non-linear activation function. You want to make sure, at the least, that the encoder and decoder activation functions are on the same scale, e.g., 0 to 1.

Answer (score 0):

If you have some kind of a dependency within your data (spatial: e.g. images, temporal: e.g. sound data, spatio-temporal: e.g. videos) it makes sense to use convolutions. If there is no such dependencies (e.g. housing price regression task) you can just use fully connected layers. You are of course not limited to these, encoder-decoder architectures are quite general and flexible. Moreover, if you want to obtain a generative model in the end, I would suggest using a variational autoencoder.

Comment: thank you, that makes sense. I am using chemical representations as my data, so will need to look into those more specifically to understand if there is dependence like this.